# How to set the marker color when using geojson.Feature

Tags: colors, geojson, marker

I am using python and my code is like:

```
from geojson import Feature, FeatureCollection
import json 
import sys, pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient(host = '..........').database
coll_name = sys.argv[1]
point_list = []
citymap_cursor = db[coll_name].find()

for doc in citymap_cursor:
    point_list.append(Feature(geometry=doc['point_latlng']))

with open('/path to/%s.json' % coll_name, 'w+') as outfile:
    json.dump(FeatureCollection(point_list), outfile)
```

By this code I got a batch of points and I can use geojson.io to visualize the points. Now these point markers are grey on geojson.io but I want them to be red. I want to know whether these is an attribute about color in geojson.Feature so that I can adjust the marker color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can manipulate the marker colors with a `marker-color` key inside the `properties` object. You pass it a hex color like `{"marker-color":"#FFF"}`. I assume you will be doing this inside your `for doc in citymap_cursor:` loop - something like `point_list.append(Feature(geometry=doc['point_latlng'],properties={'marker-color':'#FFF'}))`